# What is the difference between an array and a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a difference in functionality between a list of lists and an array?  In Python sometimes data structures are mutable or immutable.  I don't see the difference in Mathematica.

Comment: Very relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496

Comment: The two terms are used interchangeably in the Wolfram Language documentation.